# Does adding GSIs to a DynamoDB slow down write performance?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Does adding GSIs to a DynamoDB slow down write performance? For instance, if I create a DynamoDB table with 5 GSIs, are writes slower than writing to a table with no GSIs? (Assuming GSI updates are eventually consistent).

Answer (score 1):

No.  DDB writes to the to both the table and the GSI asynchronously, thus the eventual consistency.

You can request strongly consistent read of the table itself.

However, [GSI don't support strongly consistent reads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html).

> Strongly consistent reads are not supported on global secondary indexes.